# XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, vite, .env

**This problem happend while using .env file only **

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1;/account/sessions/email' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**while using .nve getting error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFf9y.png)
**Without .nve not getting error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxmB4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8OUU.png)

Why not workibg with .env file

Comment: Hello, please don't use images to share code. Also, make sure your question is written correctly and that you provide all the elements we need to examine the problem (you don't provide the .env file for example). Finally, your problem is related to CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) which is a security policy that might not be linked to the code you provide. Do you have control on the server you are trying to request ?